# Offset Plotly trace on x-axes

Tags: python, plot, plotly, trace, scatter

I'm trying to plot multiple categories on the same plot using add_trace(). Ideally, I would want the different traces to have a slight offset so that the markers don't overlap. I'm unable to figure how to achieve it.

Here is an illustrative code, and my current result. The add_trace() doesn't seem to have an argument for an offset.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig2 = go.Figure()

x_data = ['10 days', '20 days', '30 days']

y_data1 = [0.4, 0.7, 0.9]
y_err_data1 = [0.025, 0.03, 0.05]
y_data2 = [0.6, 0.65, 0.7]
y_err_data2 = [0.05, 0.03, 0.01]

fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_data,
                             y=y_data1,
                             error_y = dict(type='data', symmetric=True,  array=y_err_data1, visible=True),
                             mode = 'markers'))

fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_data,
                             y=y_data2,
                             error_y = dict(type='data', symmetric=True,  array=y_err_data2, visible=True),
                             mode = 'markers'))

fig2.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a couple modifications:

- Use `x_data=[10,20,30]` so that we can easily add/subtract to it.  Then for the x input of `go.Scatter` use something like `x_data=[i-.1 for i in x_data]` to create the offset.  Select the offset you desire, I'm using +/- 0.1 here.
- Alternatively you can use use a numpy array `x_data=np.array([10,20,30])`.  Then the x input of `go.Scatter` is a easier with `x=x_data-.1`
- Use `ticksuffix=" days"` to get the text back on your xaxis
- Use `tickvals=x_data` to specify the exact tick values.

All together:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
fig2 = go.Figure()

#x_data = [10,20,30]
x_data = np.array([10,20,30])

y_data1 = [0.4, 0.7, 0.9]
y_err_data1 = [0.025, 0.03, 0.05]
y_data2 = [0.6, 0.65, 0.7]
y_err_data2 = [0.05, 0.03, 0.01]

fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_data+0.1, #x=[i+.1 for i in x_data]
                             y=y_data1,
                             error_y = dict(type='data', symmetric=True,  array=y_err_data1, visible=True),
                             mode = 'markers'))

fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_data-0.1, #x=[i-.1 for i in x_data]
                             y=y_data2,
                             error_y = dict(type='data', symmetric=True,  array=y_err_data2, visible=True),
                             mode = 'markers'))

fig2.update_xaxes(ticksuffix=" days", tickvals=x_data)
fig2.show()
```

[image: with tick vals]

Comment: Thanks. I tried something like this. The issue is I can't seem to remove the sticks of 15 and 25 if I use x as integer values. (that if I keep the graph with the same dimensions).

Comment: Use `fig2.update_xaxes(tickvals=x_data)`, see [here](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#set-exact-location-of-axis-ticks) and added above.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to get an offset between plotly box plots belonging to the same group is using the `offsetgroup` parameter together with the `boxmode` parameter, as below.
You have to mess a little with the legend, otherwise it will show everything multiple times.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

colors={'SF Zoo': 'red', 'LA Zoo': 'blue'}

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Box(x0='giraffes', name='SF Zoo', y=[1, 2, 3], offsetgroup="SF Zoo", line_color=colors['SF Zoo']),
        go.Box(x0='giraffes', name='LA Zoo', y=[3, 4, 5], offsetgroup="LA Zoo", line_color=colors['LA Zoo']),
        go.Box(x0='elephants', name='SF Zoo', y=[1, 2, 3], offsetgroup="SF Zoo", line_color=colors['SF Zoo'], showlegend=False),
        go.Box(x0='elephants', name='LA Zoo', y=[0, 1, 2, 4], offsetgroup="LA Zoo", line_color=colors['LA Zoo'], showlegend=False)
    ]
)

fig.update_layout(boxmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]